# Cucumber error with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter` when I execute my cucumber JUnit test in Eclipse.

My environment:

```
Eclipse Neon 4.6.3
JUnit 4.12
Cucumber-core 1.2.5
Cucumber-java 1.2.5
Cucumber-junit 1.2.5
Hamcrest-core 1.3
```

Reference to cucumber in eclipse: eclipse\help\Installed software 
tab=cucumber Eclipse feature ver 0.0.17.201704062133.

Eclipse Environment Setup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJNJX.png)

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.javacodegeeks</groupId>
  <artifactId>junitcucumber</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JUnit Cucumber Example</name>
  <description>JUnit Cucumber Example</description>
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

UserSteps.java

```
package junitcucumber;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import junitcucumber.User;

public class UserSteps {

    private User user = new User();

    @Given("^that the user (.*) is given a task to clear (.*) certification exam$")
    public void certificationName(String name, String certication) throws Throwable {
        user.setName(name);
        user.setCertification(certication);
    }

    @When("^(.*) got (\\d+) marks in exam$")
    public void gotMarks(String name, int marks) throws Throwable {
        user.setName(name);
        user.setMarks(marks);
    }

    @Then("^(.*) is known as (.*) certified$")
    public void certifiedYes(String name, String certification) throws Throwable {
        assertThat(name, is(user.getName()));
        assertThat(user.getCertification(), equalTo("Java"));
        assertThat(user.getResult(), is(true));
    }
}
```

user.feature

```
Feature: User Certification

  Scenario: User is Passed
    Given that the user Vinod is given a task to clear Java certification exam
    When Vinod got 60 marks in exam
    Then Vinod is known as Java certified
```

UserTest.java

```
package junitcucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class UserTest {

}
```

User.java

```
package junitcucumber;

public class User {
    private String name;
    private String certification;
    private int marks;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCertification() {
        return certification;
    }

    public void setCertification(String certification) {
        this.certification = certification;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public boolean getResult() {
        if (this.marks < 60) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse project class path:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGZxs.png)

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory$1.<init>(PluginFactory.java:53)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.<clinit>(PluginFactory.java:52)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:70)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:25)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.formatter.Formatter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: I am using the example from the Code Geeks website.  https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-cucumber-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gherkin JAR is missing in your Java build path (see *Referenced Libraries* in your screenshot):

1. **Add [Gherkin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin) as dependeny to your `pom.xml`**.
2. **Make sure** *Maven Dependencies > gherki-2.12.2.jar > **gherkin.formatter > Formatter.class*** is available (**if not**, in the Maven repository **delete the JAR** which may be broken and rebuild the project).

Comment: Thanks.  I have added gherkin 2.12.2 jar file and still receive the same error.  I have tried adding the dependencies through maven (pom file) and alternatively just adding the requisite jar files as external jar file dependencies.

Comment: How do you execute the JUnit test in Eclipse (via Maven build or via _Run As_)?

Comment: I use the Run As... on the the UserTest junit class in the test package.

Comment: Did the Gherkin JAR show up under _Referenced Libraries_? I'm wondering why you're get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter` instead of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin.formatter.Formatter`. Do you use reflection somewhere? Could you check the build path of the launch configuration?

Comment: I do not believe that I am using reflection.  I will add an image of my eclipse build path and the contents of the files.

Comment: Is [`cucumber-java8-1.2.5.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java8/1.2.5) missing? Could you add also the stack trace to see where the error will be thrown.

Comment: I do not think I need cucumber-java8 since I'm not writing lambda expressions.  I have also update the eclipse environment image and added the stack trace.  Thank you.

Comment: I added the cucumber-java8 jar and still have the same error.

Comment: You attached the screenshot of the Java build path of the project instead of the JUnit run configuration. The JUnit run configuration can have a different build path. Could you try to delete the run configuration and do again _Run As > JUnit Test_?

Comment: I removed all the run configurations and created a new run configuration (unit) for the project junitcucumber.  I have updated the image -- Eclipse project class path.

Comment: Everything looks good. Could you navigate to _junitcucumber > Maven Dependencies > gherki-2.12.2.jar > gherkin.formatter > Formatter.class_ (maybe something is broken in the Maven repository)? Should I leave my answer (because of the comments) or delete it?

Comment: The gherkin jar file in my local maven repository was corrupt.  After removing the jar file from my local maven repository and re-fetching the maven dependencies it worked.  Thanks for your help.